# Application is stuck when receive Push notification when app is active

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

My iOS application have a functionality of adding news. when i add a news at the same time i get an alert of push notification of my news. at that time my app is in active state. When i tap on ok my app stuck. I am testing on iOS 7. i am not generating any alert when notification receive but still it is showing me notification. below is my method in APpDelegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
            if (state == UIApplicationStateActive){
            //do nothing
        }
  }
```

i am using parse.com for push notification.

```
My app get stuck if app is in active state.
```

.

Comment: push notifications are supposed to show an alert ... that's not something you can control.

Comment: okay no problem but app should not stuck

Comment: No idea what you mean by that. It doesn't respond to touches any more ?

Comment: yes exactly it stops respond to touch

Comment: can you try to remove the parse code `[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];` and, for example, just print the userInfo dict to the console. Does your app get stuck then as well?

Comment: No If I remove [PFPush handlePush:userInfo]; from app then it works normal